# Merge 2 array/Hash into 1 variable Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have 2 variables that are returned on form submission.  I need to merge the values into 1 Variable that I can use to create SQL later on.
How can I get results that is union of all the values:
i.e. location_setting = '409','405'  and Status = '501', '137', '124'

Here is my current code, but spits only values from h2

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $h1 =  {  'location_setting' => [ '409' ], 'status' => [ '501' ] };

my $h2 = {  'status' => [ '137', '124' ], 'location_setting' => ['405'], 'classification' => ['0']}; 

my $x = {%$h1, %$h2};

print Dumper $x;
```

Comment: Union even if that creates duplicate values?

Comment: I think ideally not duplicated, it won't matter to the SQL creation status in (501, 501) will list same results

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my %h =
   map {
      $_ => [
         uniq
            $h1->{$_} ? @{ $h1->{$_} } : (),
            $h2->{$_} ? @{ $h2->{$_} } : (),
      ]
   } 
      uniq
         keys(%$h1), keys(%$h2);
```

If you have lots of hashes or a variable number of hashes,

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my @hashes = ( $h1, $h2, ... );

my %h =
   map {
      my $key = $_;
      $key => [ uniq map @$_, grep $_, map $_->{$key}, @hashes ]
   } 
      uniq map keys(%$_), @hashes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my $h1 =  {  'location_setting' => [ '409' ], 'status' => [ '501' ] };

my $h2 = {  'status' => [ '137', '124' ], 'location_setting' => [], 'classification' => ['0']}; 

my %x;
foreach my $h1key (keys %{$h1}) {
    push @{$x{$h1key}}, @{${$h1}{$h1key}};
}

foreach my $h2key (keys %{$h2}) {
    push @{$x{$h2key}}, @{${$h2}{$h2key}};
}

@$_ = uniq @$_
   for values(%x);

my $x = \%x;
print Dumper $x;
```

Comment: Why are you using Data::Dumper if you're (stupidly) against external libraries?

Comment: Would have been nice to credit the [person](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1196683) from which you copied this.

Comment: still learning perl, sr folks don't want to import any library ... not my call

Comment: So why did you (Data::Dumper, and hopefully strict and warnings)?

Comment: I think that you **must** quote sources if you copy a substantial portion of it.  This one's copy-pasted.  I suggest that you edit your post and add a link to where it's taken from.